# Time-based style changer how can I do it

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain me how to do a Time-based style changer in Javascript ? I've tried to do a test but it doesn't work. It only change the style when I manually modify in the code ">" to "<" in the if statement
This is the code I used

```
var myDate = new Date();

        if(myDate.getHours() < 11.25) {

            document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = "red";

        } else {

            document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = "black";

        }
```

Comment: `getHours()` returns an integer, and never a fraction of an hour. If you want to set the styles so that the boundary is crossed when the time is past a quarter hour past 11, then you need to compare it against `getMinutes()` too

Comment: And the style is time based, so did you check it before and after 11?

Comment: I think your code should work fine, but it will only toggle at midnight and at 12:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your condition as below. `getHours` will return `integer` value of `hour` while `getMinutes` will return `integer` value of `minutes`.

```
if (myDate.getHours() < 11 || (myDate.getHours() == 11 && myDate.getMinutes() < 15)) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To further elabourate on my comment: [`getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) returns an integer only, so it will always return `11` or `12` (and etc.), and never a fraction of an hour:

> An integer number, between 0 and 23, representing the hour for the given date according to local time.

Therefore, comparing it against a non-integer value doesn't make a lot of sense in your case.

If you want to set up the `if` statement such that a certain style should be applied before a quarter past 11, then you need to compare it against [`getMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes) too. This is assuming that by `11.25` you mean `11 hour + 0.25 hour`, where 0.25h = 15mins:

```
if (myDate.getHours() === 11 && myDate.getMinutes() < 15 || myDate.getHours() < 11) {
  // Logic here
}
```